# protractor - testing rest end point

Tags: rest, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to invoke rest end point from Protractor E2E tests. I have referred to following site, however this post seems to be based on old API

eg: `protractor.promise.defer();`  seems no longer valid on latest API.

http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/

Could you please advise/give sample code to invoke rest end point based on latest protractor API (>= 1.3).

I'm trying to write generic function, something like following.

```
var executeRequest = function(method, url) {
     var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

     // method can be ‘GET’, ‘POST’ or ‘PUT’
     request({uri: url, method: method, json: true}, function(error, response, body) {

        if (error || response.statusCode >= 400) {
          defer.reject({
            error : error,
            message : response
          });
        } else {
          defer.fulfill(body);
        }
     });

     // Return a promise so the caller can wait on it for the request to complete
     return defer.promise;
};
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) instead. Example from their website...

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options = {
  uri : 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php',
  method : 'POST'
};

rp(options)
  .then(console.dir)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used npm module - "needle" to invoke restAPI . That has option for redirects, which helped to validate test site even after redirect.

Please find below sample test to validate rest endpoint is up and running.

it("check restendpoint service is running", function(done){

```
var restendpointUrl = browser.baseUrl + 'service'; 

needle.get(healthcheckUrl,{follow_max : 5}, function(err,resp) {

        expect(resp.statusCode).toBe(200);
        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {

            expect(true).toBe(true);

        } else {
            expect(false).toBe(true);
        }
            done();

   });

});
```

Brine, many thanks for your earlier reply.